# Schedule silent mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm now developing a simple android app to schedule silent mode on weekdays at time specified by user (for students and workers during their work time). Is alarmmanager the right choice for scheduling here ? Or what else ?

Comment: I am afraid that to provide the answer, we need to know the question :-) Please describe what you are currently have done and on what you stuck. See also: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think it's more clear now...